# Meteor import of SimplSchema not working

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I am trying to get access to objects using import, but am struggling with the logic:

schemas.js:

```
import { SimpleSchema } from 'meteor/aldeed:simple-schema';
export default UsersExtraSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    ...
}
```

seed.js:

```
import '/imports/startup/server/schemas.js';
export default class SeedDB {

    loadBaseData() {
        ....
        UsersExtraSchema.validate(attr);
        ...
    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'
at SeedDB.loadBaseData (imports/startup/server/seed.js:19:26)
at server/main.js:11:14
at /tidee/app/tidee-meteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:290:5
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you import like this?

```
import UsersExtraSchema from '/imports/startup/server/schemas.js';
```